# What is the term you use for a user that is a developer?

Tags: user-stories, terminology

When developing a UI components software library, the "immediate" user of the library is not the end user interacting with the components on a website, but the developer who takes those components and puts them into their own website.

Is there a standard term for this kind of developer user?

Take for example a user story where the beneficiary is a developer:

> As a [developer user] of component X, I want to be able to set the background color of component X, so I can better integrate the component X into my website.

But there might be stories for the end user as well:

> As an end user of component X, I want to be able to use the Enter key to make a selection, so that I don't have to use the mouse.

Comment: Similar question https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/26881/how-to-chose-the-right-perspective-in-user-stories

Comment: As a consumer of component X, or as an integrator of component X, maybe? It really depends on the value they are getting from that. Do you really need to differentiate and express it as a user story format. Your backlog does not need to contain all user stories. For more technical tasks like these, a different format might work better.

Comment: @Bogdan "Consumer of component X" is a very good name, better than any I thought of until now. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just keep it simple, use the term developer? What kind of problem do you fear that this might give you?

Harry

Comment: Good question. A developer is also a person developing the library (part of my team). We have developers and testers in the team and I think using "developer" for the people that are using the library would be a bit confusing.

Comment: Developers are stakeholders to the project, and therefore legitimate subjects of the user story. I would not shy away from using "developer" as the subject of the user story.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a persona list defined for your product. Your user stores should reference those personas in the "As a [X]..." part. Sometimes companies even give real person names to those personas and refer to those names as "As John, I want to ...".

As long as your actor ( persona ), the action, and the result make sense, the naming is not so much important; the most important part of it is consistency.

Comment: Perfectly agree, but my problem is exactly the "naming" part. I didn't find yet a satisfactory name for this persona.